# Vuetify size of v-avatar in v-toolbar based on screen width

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a v-avatar to display a clickable user profile picture in my toolbar, not too dissimilar to what Google goes in their toolbars. The main problem is, while I am testing different screen widths, the toolbar size changes. I understand this is part of Material Design, and that based on the type of screen, it may be 48, 56, or 64 pixels.

How to dynamically resize my icons based on the screen size? V-avatar takes a `size` attribute and when I try to do it by `%` I am getting really wonky results.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this solution to avoid the problem, I found no other easier way to resize the v-avatar or the v-icon in vuetify:

```
<template>
[...]
  <v-avatar :image="user.avatarURL" :size="avatarSize"/>
</template>


<script>
import { ref, watchEffect, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'
[...]
function calculateAvatarSize() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1500) {
        return 64
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        return 56
    } else {
        return 48
    }
}

const avatarSize = ref(calculateAvatarSize())

onMounted(async() => {
    watchEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            avatarSize.value = calculateAvatarSize()
        })
    })
})

onUnmounted(async() => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {
        avatarSize.value = calculateAvatarSize()
    })
})
</script>
```

Hope it will help others struggling with the same issue.